# Python virtualenv bin scripts always exit with code 1

Tags: python, setup.py, python-venv

I have a virtualenv with some scripts/applications that come packaged with my application.

Suppose it looks something like this:

`ls /venv/bin/`

```
activate
myscript
python
...
```

When I run `myscript` with either

```
/venv/bin/python /venv/bin/myscript
```

or

```
/venv/bin/myscript
```

I properly execute `myscript`; however, the returned exit status is coming back with 1 when I know it is succeeding.

`myscript` is being copied to `/bin` via `entry_point` scripts in setup.py:

```
entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
        'myscript=myscript.__main__:main',
      ],
},
```

I see that the *actual* version of `myscript` copied over has some extra code in it that could be corrupting the exit.

Is there a proper way to run packages that exist in the `/venv/bin` to avoid bad exit codes?

---

Extra info:

The executable itself looks like:

```
from myscript.__main__ import main
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())
```

Comment: Try moving it out of the folder

Comment: I copied to a different directory and I dont see a change in the exit status code.

Comment: Me too. Maybe try deleting the extra code, or at least showing it to us

Comment: Can you diff the scripts and post the extra code?

Comment: updated the question

Comment: It appears that all the executable is doing is importing the actual library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was a result of the `myscript.py` code. In this file, the code exits when it hits:

`return "Something that the user would see"`

When `myscript.py` is run directly from the terminal, its exit code is 0.

When it is invoked within a separate file (in my case, the wrapper script that is packaged as a `console_scripts`), its exit code is 1. The code is called with this line (with `main` being `myscript.py`):

`sys.exit(main())`

I believe this is because sys exit takes any non 0 returned value as exit code 1 (exception).

Changing my code in `myscript.py` to `log` the output instead of return it, fixed the exit code issue.